# How to simplify 64 levels of nesting formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I encountered "64 levels of nesting" issue while working on my formula. Is there any way to simplify this formula? This formula worked fine up from 10 to 500 (G:G) but once over 510 something, it encountered "64 levels of nesting" issue. I found some solutions that involved lookup and match-index, but I can't see where/how to implement it here.

[image: excel screenshot]

Formula is in cell B3:

```
=IF(B2<=$G$2,B2+($E$2*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$2,B2<=$G$3),B2+($E$3*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$3,B2<=$G$4),B2+($E$4*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$4,B2<=$G$5),B2+($E$5*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$5,B2<=$G$6),B2+($E$6*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$6,B2<=$G$7),B2+($E$7*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$7,B2<=$G$8),B2+($E$8*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$8,B2<=$G$9),B2+($E$9*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$9,B2<=$G$10),B2+($E$10*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$10,B2<=$G$11),B2+($E$11*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$11,B2<=$G$12),B2+($E$12*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$12,B2<=$G$13),B2+($E$13*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$13,B2<=$G$14),B2+($E$14*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$14,B2<=$G$15),B2+($E$15*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$15,B2<=$G$16),B2+($E$16*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$16,B2<=$G$17),B2+($E$17*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$17,B2<=$G$18),B2+($E$18*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$18,B2<=$G$19),B2+($E$19*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$19,B2<=$G$20),B2+($E$20*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$20,B2<=$G$21),B2+($E$21*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$21,B2<=$G$22),B2+($E$22*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$22,B2<=$G$23),B2+($E$23*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$23,B2<=$G$24),B2+($E$24*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$24,B2<=$G$25),B2+($E$25*B2),IF(AND(B2>$G$25,B2<=$G$26),B2+($E$26*B2))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Cells $A2:$A26 & cells $E2:$E26 are variable. Cells $D2:$D26 are just my indicator. Others are constant value.

Cells $B2:$B26 will calculate the formula $A2+$A2* **percentage**. The **percentage** is based on the value which is in cells $E2:$E26. The value is then determine by the value in cells $A2:$A26.

Formula in cells $B2:$B26 are as previous formula dragged down.

Example:

If the cost is 50. The value of **percentage** will be taken from cell $E$7. In this case is 10 thus returning the value in $B$6 to $A6+$A6*10=55

Please refer to ss 2.

[excel screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toyPr.jpg)

Comment: I tried to decipher it, but I supposed I might just ask - what are you trying to accomplish with this? Can you explain the thing you are trying to do in words?

Comment: Appreciate the replies, but the formula doesn't do what I'm intended. My mistake most of it as my intention wasn't structured properly in the beginning. OP have been added some more details on the intended goal. Maybe I'll try to tweak and work around based on the suggested formula a bit but suggestion are still very much welcome. Guess "writer block" also exist while writing excel formula.

Answer (score 2):

If you reach the nesting limit that nearly always means there's an easier way....

You should be able to do this much more simply with a **lookup** type formula, e.g.

`=B2+B2*IF(B2<G$2,E$2,INDEX(E$3:E$26,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2>G$2:G$25,0),0))`

This finds the first value in column `G` which is > `B2` and then gets the required value from the next row in column `E`

The only thing this formula doesn't do is impose an upper limit on `B2` (yours is the `G26` value `250`). If that's an issue you can just add an extra IF to cater for that

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rework your tables but an INDEX/MATCH with a relative lookup on ascending data will return the correct percentage.

```
=b2*index(e2:e26, match(b2, g2:g26, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand your formula/intent. I think I got it...if not please clarify.

add another column that does the math in column H. enter this formula and drag down.

=($B$2+(E2*$B$2))

in cell B3 enter this formula

=VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(B2,-1),G:H,2,FALSE)